# Error while opening multiple json files in R

Tags: r, json

I am very new to r and json. And I am trying to read multiple json files located in one folder using R

```
filenames <- list.files("./data/1st-transcripts",
                         pattern="*.json", full.names=TRUE)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, fromJSON)
```

But while running the above code, I am getting following error

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
           true, "__ts": 1662058422212}{"_id": "6310f7d09e646801f2ca0a
                     (right here) ------^
```

I tried using `stream_in(file(path))` and `readLines()` but it doesn't work.
How can I fix this error?

I will really appreciate any help or suggestion

Comment: The `pattern` argument of `list.files` expects a regular expression, not a glob. Use `".*\\.json$"` instead of what you wrote. — But, regarding your error message, that’s unrelated to your code or to the fact that you are dealing with multiple JSON files; instead, it simply looks as if one or more of your JSON files are invalid.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Thanks for your input but when I am trying to run `ldf <- lapply(filenames, fromJSON)` is am getting above error. I have more than 13000 json files and it is difficult to check which json file is invalid

Comment: You can use a debugger to find out which file failed. For example, you can set [`options(error = recover)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/recover.html) before running the statement, and then you can go through the call stack and find out which file is currently being run.  But it’s maybe simpler to just change your code so that it prints the fiel that is being parsed. Or, slightly more elegantly, wrap the reading into a `tryCatch` block and print only the file that fails.